# How to avoid "unresolved function" error with TypeScript mixins?

Tags: typescript, webstorm, durandal

WebStorm is reporting an unresolved function when I use Durandal's `Events.includeIn()` mixin method on a TypeScript class:

```
class Foo {
  bar() {
    ...
    this.trigger('myEvent', payload);  // trigger is unresolved function
    ...
  }
}

Events.includeIn(Foo);
```

Is there a way to resolve this without using WebStorm to suppress each unresolved call?

Comment: Quick workaround: `this['trigger']('myEvent', payload);` :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to call the `trigger` method on the `Foo` class, you will need to inform the TypeScript compiler about the `trigger` method.  You can do this by declaring the methods that *will* exist after the `includeIn` call in the class definition:

```
class Foo {

  // I'm not sure of the exact parameter/return types
  trigger: (eventName: string, payload: any) => void;

  bar() {
    ...
    this.trigger('myEvent', payload);  // now this function exists
    ...
  }
}

Events.includeIn(Foo);
```